# How to publish in order to resolve latest.integration with gradle?

Tags: continuous-integration, gradle

What I have is a maven repository (nexus) to which maven has been publishing.  In each artifact version folder in my artifact repository folder there are the standard maven artifacts: a maven-metadata.xml, a jar, and a pom.xml, etc.

Now I want to resolve these using gradle.  In my gradle.build file if I list them as:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.company', name: 'artifact', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Then they will resolve correctly.  However, I want to use the version "latest.integration" so that I can automatically integrate the latest versions of my dependencies.  When I do this though, gradle fails to resolve it.

I imagine that gradle is looking for some ivy specific files that maven is not publishing up to the repository in order to resolve latest.integration, but I am not sure.  Should I go back and re-publish all of my upstream dependencies with gradle before trying to resolve down stream?  It would seem that since gradle supports maven repositories under the repositories element that it should already know how to interpret "latest.integration" for that repository type.

This is my repositories section:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://<server>/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots" }
}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`latest.integration` is an Ivy concept, and only works for Ivy repositories. In other words, both publication and consumption would have to happen in an Ivy-compatible manner. (Gradle is capable of this; not sure about Nexus.)

The obvious alternative is to use Maven snapshot dependencies. What do you hope to gain from using `latest.integration`?

Comment: this is covered in the gradle manual ch 48.2.4 where it discusses dynamic version vs changing module.  the manual seems to suggest that gradle can resolve both using latest.integration? http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

Comment: I'm not aware of `latest.integration` support for Maven repositories. At least it's not a documented feature.

Comment: ok, that did the trick, i had to change my uploadArchives repository as well as my regular respositories to ivy type (from maven) and it worked from there!